# azure portal move resources from one rg to another : error Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined

Tags: azure

I am trying to move my azure resources from one resource group to another and getting validation error.But the error message is too confusing

```
{
  "message": "Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined",
  "name": "TypeError",
  "stack": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseJSON' of undefined\n    at c (https://portal.azure.com/AzureHubs/Content/Dynamic/BelzPLa-5LK8.js:2:668)\n    at o (https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/uy7P2dwIDVkF.js:4:72)\n    at https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/uy7P2dwIDVkF.js:4:5594"
}
```

Any suggestions for how to find out the actual error?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the account that you are doing this with has permission in both the destination Resource Group AND the destination Subscription. Go to IAM settings for both of those and make sure the user is added as an owner or administrator.